# Editable table with AutoForm in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform

How can I make a table with input fields in Meteor. I've used the example from http://autoform.meteor.com/update-each but they only use 1 input field.

The functionality works with this code:

```
  <tbody>
    {{#each persons}}
      {{#autoForm id=makeUniqueID type="update" collection=Collections.Persons doc=this autosave=true}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{> afFieldInput name="fullName" label=false}}</td>
        <td>{{> afFieldInput name="email" label=false}}</td>
        <td>{{> afFieldInput name="address" label=false}}</td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      {{/autoForm}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

but it created a `<form>` element around each `<tr>` and it screws up my html. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: A form in a table is no valid HTML. The form should wrap around the table, or should be inside a `<td>`. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576976/where-are-the-form-elements-allowed-within-a-table-element

Comment: But `{{#autoForm id=makeUniqueID type="update" collection=Collections.Persons doc=this autosave=true}}` has to be inside my for each loop. So I don't know what to do.

Comment: You could use divs instead of table, and fake the table-layout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049149/how-to-achieve-table-layout-without-using-tables

Comment: @Jamgreen have you found a solution yet? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Use `div`s with CSS:

```
<div class="table">
  {{#each persons}}
    {{autoform class="tr"}}
      <div class="td">{{> afQuickField}}</div>
      <div class="td">{{> afQuickField}}</div>
      <div class="td">{{> afQuickField}}</div>
    {{/autoform}}
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

And style it as such:

```
.table {
  display: table;
}

.tr {
  display: table-row;
}

.td {
  display: table-cell
}
```